# Find difference month on month between rows in a 3 level multiIndex where they match on 2 levels in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I need your help. I have been staring at this all day. I am trying to find the difference in each of the last 4 numerical columns between this month end and last month end if they match on level 1 (bucket) and level 2 (Salary) but level 0 are the dates I need to assess.

```
                                Price   Cost    Value   Gross
Date        Bucket  Salary              
2021-10-31  30DPD   2 Missed    3.33    3.07    92,508.65   153,493.06
                    3 Missed    1.91    2.69    25,961.60   71,329.51
                    4-5 Missed  0.68    0.84    13,819.31   28,759.36
                    6-12 Missed 0.29    1.00    405.33      6,909.69
                    
2021-11-30  30DPD   1 Missed    5.42    3.86    36,345.48   97,378.17
                    2 Missed    55.75   46.11   473,204.30  1,150,866.42
                    3 Missed    38.50   33.43   452,324.33  998,917.02
                    4-5 Missed  46.67   38.26   529,012.51  1,327,705.85
                    6-12 Missed 59.56   59.29   705,956.78  1,840,849.20
```

Not sure how to use the full power of multiIndexes to access data and add logical filters.

I tried the below approach but to no avail.

```
summary['Price_diff'] = np.nan

for idx in summary.index.levels[0]:
    summary.Price_diff[idx] = summary.Price[idx].diff()
```

How do I make this happen?

Comment: kindly provide the data in dict form : ``df.to_dict()`` and also post your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is unclear but are you looking for something like that?

```
>>> df.groupby(['Bucket', 'Salary']).diff()

                               Price   Cost      Value       Gross
Date       Bucket Salary                                          
2021-10-31 30DPD  2 Missed       NaN    NaN        NaN         NaN
                  3 Missed       NaN    NaN        NaN         NaN
                  4-5 Missed     NaN    NaN        NaN         NaN
                  6-12 Missed    NaN    NaN        NaN         NaN
2021-11-30 30DPD  1 Missed       NaN    NaN        NaN         NaN
                  2 Missed     52.42  43.04  380695.65   997373.36
                  3 Missed     36.59  30.74  426362.73   927587.51
                  4-5 Missed   45.99  37.42  515193.20  1298946.49
                  6-12 Missed  59.27  58.29  705551.45  1833939.51
```

Setup [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be reproducible:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

data = {'Date': [Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-10-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-11-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-11-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-11-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-11-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-11-30 00:00:00')], 
        'Bucket': ['30DPD', '30DPD', '30DPD', '30DPD', '30DPD', '30DPD', '30DPD', '30DPD', '30DPD'],
        'Salary': ['2 Missed', '3 Missed', '4-5 Missed', '6-12 Missed', '1 Missed', '2 Missed', '3 Missed', '4-5 Missed', '6-12 Missed'], 
        'Price': [3.33, 1.91, 0.68, 0.29, 5.42, 55.75, 38.5, 46.67, 59.56],
        'Cost': [3.07, 2.69, 0.84, 1.0, 3.86, 46.11, 33.43, 38.26, 59.29],
        'Value': [92508.65, 25961.6, 13819.31, 405.33, 36345.48, 473204.3, 452324.33, 529012.51, 705956.78],
        'Gross': [153493.06, 71329.51, 28759.36, 6909.69, 97378.17, 1150866.42, 998917.02, 1327705.85, 1840849.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['Date', 'Bucket', 'Salary'])
```